# Reading from /dev/hidraw1 device connected to linux system

Tags: linux, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a QR/Bar code scanner connected to my linux system, which comes up as /dev/hidraw1 device.
If I do `ls -la /dev/hidraw*` I get

```
crw------- 1 root root 248, 0 May  5 10:18 /dev/hidraw0
crw------- 1 root root 248, 1 May  5 11:05 /dev/hidraw1
```

Whenever I try to read from this device using `cat /dev/hidraw1` command I get a lot of junk data along with the encoded data also the it doesn't comes up in a formatted way. Here is the output of one of the QR code

```
    68<,?
          .4xml ve7'rsion4="1

..0"4    encod-%in4876g=
                                   "UTF-8"?><PrintLetterB,
                                                                       .arcod4e&D!'ata"&% ' uid=$"12345,.678",name=
                                                                                                                                      "Rohit 4Ka,
poo.44r,."4 gend&& er=4"M,."4 yob=8"319,93" co
                                                              ="S

                                                                  ,/O:
                                                                        Mukesh  4,
```

Why its not coming in continuous readable string, changing the Baud-rate also didn't made any difference.
[Here is the screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYrL0.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a HID device, not an RS-232 one. The protocol it uses is binary. What you really get each time you `read()` from the device is a HID report, not a text line.

The format of the report varies from device to device. The HID specification mandates that the device publishes a HID report descriptor that describes the format of the report. That is... complicated, but if you only want to work with this particular device you can just look at the read reports and try to deduce what it means.

In my experience, barcode scanners usually contain a small header and then the payload data. The header usually has fields for the barcode type and the length of the data. And since the report size is fixed, but the barcodes are arbitrarily long, long barcodes are split into multiples reports, so there are also flags to signal whether this is a first, continuation or last block.

If you want to post dumps of the device, for further analysis, please do not use `cat`. Use `hexdump -C` or `od -tx1` or something similar that shows the proper binary data.

Comment: I don't need binary data. I want it in a readable string. The problem which I am facing is whenever I unplug the device, I get the result in proper readable string but when i scan continuously I get it in the above shown format.

Comment: @user7345878: I really doubt you will get anything at all when you _unplug_ the device...

Comment: @user7345878: Ahhh, that is because your scanner is configured in mode "Emulate Keyboard". Reading `hidraw` you are getting standard keyboard 
HID reports, as if keys were typed. The kernel sees it also as a keyboard, and sends the typed text to the console, but the console is busy with the `cat` so while the data is echoed to the screen and messed all messed with the binary data, it is also buffered in stdin. Then, when `cat` is eventually killed, all the stdin buffer is dumped as plain text.

Comment: thanks for explaining. Didn't had this clue. So how to read the QR code in string format? Do I have to write own code to read efficiently from `/dev/hidraw` port or any shell command can do the job ??

Comment: @user7345878: Well, the easiest way is to just read from `stdin` as it were a real keyboard. If you want to treat it as an independent device then there are many options, but more complicated...

Comment: Well i didn't get the `stdin` method, are you referring to `/dev/hidraw` or /dev/input/event[x]` ? How I should read the scanner to get readable decoded string.

Comment: @user7345878: You could use `/dev/input/event*` but I was referring to using normal _read-from-user_ text, such as `scanf()`.

Comment: Most of the problem is solved. Can I redirect the output from the `/dev/input/event*` to a file instead of displaying it to console/x11 terminal. I want to store that decoded string into a file. Normal redirection doesn't works on this. Is there any other way to redirect the output to a txt file ?

Comment: @user7345878: You could do `cat /dev/input/event* > file` but `event*` are not text files, you will read key-press and key-release events. If you want to get the text from standard input just do `cat > file`. When `cat` takes no input name it will read from standard input.

Comment: thanks for mentioning this "When cat takes no input name it will read from standard input". I was totally lost in the loop of hidraw and wasn't thinking in that angle that it can be treated as stdin. I was running behind to redirect the stdin to a file. But this clue solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Most scanners can be configured as HID device or USB CDC device.  Check the manual of your scanner for sth like "USB Interface Configuration" and see if it can be set to USB CDC (or USB Com Port Emulation).  If it can, it will attach on linux as /dev/ttyACM* and provide data as a serial stream, which is easier to read.