# Data from Serial Port Always Empty

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, barcode-scanner, hid, ubuntu-22.04

I have a USB Barcode Scanner and plug into my Ubuntu PC. The Scanner is working properly, since when I used it, it will output the result of barcode on every cursor I put (such as terminal, vscode, etc.) but the `received_string` variable is always empty. There are no erros. Do you have any idea?

```
import serial
import time

SerialObj = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)

time.sleep(3)

SerialObj.timeout(3)

print("Starting")

while True:
    received_string = SerialObj.readline()
    print("Received: ", received_string)

SerialObj.close()
```

I want to retrieve the data using Serial with the code, so the variable `received_string` will be assign with the value of the scanner data, but I always get `Received: b''`.

**UPDATE**
here are output when i did `sudo dmesg | tail` without plug the scanner in

```
[85989.229043] usb 1-10.1: USB disconnect, device number 15
[85995.490066] usb 1-10.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[85995.606922] usb 1-10.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[85995.608536] usb 1-10.1: New USB device found, idVendor=060e, idProduct=7800, bcdDevice= 2.54
[85995.608538] usb 1-10.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[85995.608539] usb 1-10.1: Product: USB Barcode Scanner HID
[85995.608540] usb 1-10.1: Manufacturer: USB Barcode Scanner HID
[85995.615660] input: USB Barcode Scanner HID USB Barcode Scanner HID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10.1/1-10.1:1.0/0003:060E:7800.0010/input/input43
[85995.674330] hid-generic 0003:060E:7800.0010: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [USB Barcode Scanner HID USB Barcode Scanner HID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10.1/input0
[87124.076792] usb 1-10.1: USB disconnect, device number 16
```

and here are output when i did `sudo dmesg | tail` with plug the scanner in

```
[85995.674330] hid-generic 0003:060E:7800.0010: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [USB Barcode Scanner HID USB Barcode Scanner HID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10.1/input0
[87124.076792] usb 1-10.1: USB disconnect, device number 16
[89435.842374] usb 1-10.2: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[89435.963057] usb 1-10.2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[89435.964477] usb 1-10.2: New USB device found, idVendor=060e, idProduct=7800, bcdDevice= 2.54
[89435.964479] usb 1-10.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[89435.964480] usb 1-10.2: Product: USB Barcode Scanner HID
[89435.964481] usb 1-10.2: Manufacturer: USB Barcode Scanner HID
[89435.970627] input: USB Barcode Scanner HID USB Barcode Scanner HID as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10.2/1-10.2:1.0/0003:060E:7800.0011/input/input44
[89436.030645] hid-generic 0003:060E:7800.0011: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [USB Barcode Scanner HID USB Barcode Scanner HID] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10.2/input0
```

Comment: Your code is trying to fetch data using `readline()`.  Perhaps the scanner is not sending a line (i.e. characters terminated with an End-of-Line character, such as a Line Feed,  '\n'). IOW a "*string*" is not necessarily a line.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. i've tried change the `readline()` into `read()`, but it still got nothing. for your information, i used ubuntu 22.04, and when i pluged the scanner and i do command `lsusb` it give me some line include, `Bus 001 Device 015: ID 060e:7800 Transmonde Technologies, Inc. USB Barcode Sanner` and when i check using `sudo dmesg | grep tty` it give me some lines include `[0.308751] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A` when i pluged or unpluged the scanner. Do you have any other ideas @sawdust. Thanks

Comment: Oops, just noticed that your code is reading from the incorrect device. `/dev/ttyS0` is a real serial port using a UART. A serial terminal using the USB interface would instead have a device name of either `/dev/ttyUSBn` (for a serial adapter) or `/dev/ttyACMn` (for serial emulation over USB). Connect the USB device, and then review the last 10 or so messages from the **dmesg** command. (Do not filter the output with **grep**.) See https://superuser.com/questions/1825431/ttyusb-serial-device-not-being-created-in-ubuntu18-04#comment2875616_1825431

Comment: i did the dmesg without filter it before and after i plug the scanner device, and add the output at the update above. so, do you know what's port name should i used?

Comment: Your scanner is reporting itself as a Human Interface Device, aka HID (rather than a terminal, i.e. a tty), and is using the *generic* interface, which is **/dev/input/***. Note that reading such an input "device" returns an event report, rather than just the payload data. This scanner seems to be also treated as a keyboard. Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797666/reading-from-dev-hidraw1-device-connected-to-linux-system

Comment: i've realize that it's hid lately, but i tried and still got error. but from your recommendation i could retrieve the data from scanner, and yeah it works. thank you so much.